# Using MCA/PCA together?

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, correspondence-analysis

If I have a large dataset with continuous, discrete, and categorical data, is it appropriate to use MCA on the categorical features and PCA on the continuous, separately?

I'm preprocessing my data right now, and am currently one-hot encoding all my categorical features. This has added far more columns (3x) to my dataset than originally, is this a problem if I was going to use, say LDA or Random Forest for feature selection?

Comment: Depends on what your question is? You could fit a principle components analysis (PCA) to the numerical data and then potentially use a permutational multivariate analysis of variance (PERMANOVA) / bubble plots to integrate your categorical variables. Also, please define acronyms before using them.

Comment: Is there a reason you would use a PERMANOVA over multiple correspondence analysis or discriminant correspondence analysis for categorical. And just to confirm, you are saying that there wouldn't be an issue treating them separately correct?

Comment: Categorical PCA (CatPca) sometimes called Nonlinear factor analysis is a general method of dimensionality reduction for a _mixture_ of numeric and categorical features. MCA can be seen as a particular case of this method, as usual PCA is, too. So, you can use it with your mixture.